# Partially left aligned and partially right aligned text in a TextView. Why isn't this working?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm having an issue with an textview in which i have some text that is supposed to be left aligned and some text that is supposed to be right aligned.

Here´s my attempt.

```
String LeftText = "LEFT";
String RightText = "RIGHT";


String resultText = LeftText + "  " + RightText;
SpannableString styledResultText = new SpannableString(resultText);
styledResultText.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE), LeftText.length() + 1, LeftText.length() + 2 + RightText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(styledResultText);
```

And here´s the xml for the textview.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
/>
```

However this is not working. All the text is getting left aligned. What am I missing here?

Comment: What stops you from creating one left-aligned TextView and another right-aligned TextView?

Comment: The thing is i want to be able to scroll through it. I have now realized i can use a scrollview for that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use TabStopSpan to solve the problem pretty easily if rightText is doesn't need to be right justified against the edge.

```
final TextView tv = ...
int column = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                (float) 200.0, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

SpannableStringBuilder textspan = new SpannableStringBuilder("Charges\nPrice\t$25.00\nShipping\t$155.08\nTax\t$5.11\n");
textspan.setSpan(new TabStopSpan.Standard(column), 0, textspan.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(textspan);
```

if you want it moved near to the right edge of your text view you can set the Tab stop after layout using a global layout listener. Then you can use the width of the textview to set a tabstop near the edge.

If you want it right aligned you just need to make a class extending ReplacementSpan that will justify the text for you..

Answer (score 0):

I've gone down this road myself...unfortunately, from my research I don't believe it's possible to have two alignment spans for a single line of text. You'll have to split it out into two different `TextView` objects.

Comment: Okay then i got to ask a counterquestion. I want to be able to drag this view so that it can hold more lines than the screen can view at once. But the suer can click and drag. This is simple to do if you had only one textview. But how would i do it with 2 textviews?