# TabStopSpan.Standard constructor parameter

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

Does anyone knows what the parameter (where) in the  TabStopSpan.Standard constructor represents ?
is it pixels ? 
According to some tests that I did, it doesn't represent pixels, I simply draw gridline and added tab stop to textview, and if for example I set the tab to 200 it doesn't do 200 pixels, this is important for different devices with different screen dpi, so if I set it 200 on one device it's going to look different that I planned, so does anyone has any clue how to figure this out ?
I tried to look on the src it doesn't help, and searched on google no luck too, I thought maybe one of you can assist here...

Thanks :)

Comment: its an offset: see android.text.Layout docs for offset meaning

Comment: offset in layout is different from the offset that mentioned here, that what makes it so confusable, it is not the offset that for sure !

Comment: P.S. I don't know why they say that it's the offset, probably someone over there worked late that night when he/she wrote it.

Comment: see: http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/style/TabStopSpan.java and http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/s?refs=getTabStop&project=frameworks where getTabStop() is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok After researching it even further, I found the answer, it is in pixels but in DIP device independent pixels, so there is a need to convert it, I found it under this question 
[Partially left aligned and partially right aligned text in a TextView. Why isn't this working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551759/partially-left-aligned-and-partially-right-aligned-text-in-a-textview-why-isn)'t

it isn't really about tabstop, but the answer answers it too.

pskink thank you for looing into it :)